# My test and train data has the same number of columns but OneHotEncoder creates different size of matrixes

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, random-forest

I am trying to create a model with train and test datasets which are seperate. They have same number of columns. When I try to encode categorical features the created matrix by OneHotEncoder is comes with different size So I cannot predict my test data since number of features are different.

both dataframes have same number of columns

```
one_hot= OneHotEncoder()
transformer= ColumnTransformer([("one_hot",one_hot,categorical_features)],
                              remainder="passthrough")

train_transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(bigdata_zeros,columns=categorical_features))
train_transformed_X_test=transformer.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(bigdata_test_zeros,columns=categorical_features))
```

Then I build my model

```
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(train_transformed_X,y_train)
```

Then I want to see the predictions with the test data

```
model.predict(train_transformed_X_test)
```

but I got the following error

```
ValueError: X has 256 features, but RandomForestRegressor is expecting 268 features as input.
```

When I check  train_transformed_X and train_transformed_X_test I can see their size is different.

I tried to create a ML model with train and test data seperated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing more about the underlying data. But it's probably due to you doing the encoding AFTER doing your test/train split.

**Try doing the one hot encoding on the entire population and THEN split into train and test sets.**

One hot encoding creates a column for each unique value in a given column. So it's possible there are different numbers of unique values within any given column in your test and train sets, leading to different numbers of columns after the encoding.

Comment: I don't split anything I have 2 separate csv data. One for the train the other one is for test

Comment: Look at the unique values in a given column and see if/how they differ between test/train set. For example, if there is a column 'bar' - look at df['bar'].unique() in both sets of data. It's most likely there are more unique values in one set and the onehotencoder is making more columns bc of that. Try combining the two sets into one, THEN onehotencoding. THEN split back into the test/train sets of data.